Clickhouse combine multiple row vectors/arrays as an average
In Clickhouse, I have a table like so:
    ID | frame | vector
    123, 0, [-0.1,0.3,0.2]
    123, 1, [0.3, 0.2, -0.1]
    456, 0, [-0.2, 0.1, 0.2]

I want to query this data so that it outputs:
    ID | avg_vector
    123, [0.1, 0.25, 0.05]
    456, [-0.2, 0.1, 0.2]

but the functions i seem to find only provide averaging an array, not averaging two arrays together.
i tried:
    SELECT
    id,
    arrayMap(
        i -> arrayReduce('avg', arrayMap(x -> x[i], groupArray(vector))),
        range(3)
    ) AS avg_vector
    FROM embeddings
    GROUP BY id

but this I believe is working across each element, not between arrays

avgForEach function
WITH vectors AS
   (
       SELECT c1 AS vector
       FROM VALUES([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12])
   )
SELECT avgForEach(vector) AS centroid
FROM vectors

┌─centroid──┐
│ [5,6,7,8] │
└───────────┘

